# Amarok2 "Search Collection" shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, search, amarok

Is there a way to make a shortcut for amarok2 that would put focus on the search collection box?

Comment: Is this a keyboard shortcut, or a desktop shortcut?

Comment: it's a keyboard shortcut.. I don't even see how a desktop shortcut would be of any use here.. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this at the moment.

Comment: Wow, I couldn't believe this so just fired it up to have a look. It seems like they went all out to make this hard. You can't even use a shortcut to focus on some other feature and then tab to it! You should report a bug to the Amarak team to add the search fields to the lists of things you can set shorcuts for.